# PHP If array_key_exists, variable equals array value: How?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I combined two arrays to create the following array, named **$group_wages_array**:

```
Array ( [1] => 500 [4] => 44 [6] => 80 [3] => 11.25 )
```

I am trying to test if the array key matches X, set a variable as it's value. Here's what I have:

NOTE: This whole thing is executed in a while loop, so the value of $thegroup['group_id'] will change. I've set it's value as "6" for this example.

```
$thegroup['group_id'] = "6" // This particular group (for simplicity)

if (array_key_exists($thegroup['group_id'], $group_wages_array)) {

    $this_wages = // Need this to be 80... how do I do it?

}
```

So, how do I get $this_wages to equal the key value?

Comment: That should work. If not, try casting `$thegroup['group_id']` to an int.

Comment: You can use anything you want as an array key, as long as PHP can typecast it to a string or an integer. This includes embedding one array reference inside another: `$outer[$inner[1]]`, so `$group_wages_array[$thegroup['group_id']]`.

Comment: +1 for going into detail about what your variables are and how they're being used. I wish more people would do that instead of just dumping code without sufficient context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just use the key from the array to get it:

```
$thegroup['group_id'] = "6" // This particular group (for simplicity)

if (array_key_exists($thegroup['group_id'], $group_wages_array)) {
    $this_wages = $group_wages_array[$thegroup['group_id']];
}
```

Also, the array keys are not 0,1,2,etc because you explicitly set them in `Array ( [1] => 500 [4] => 44 [6] => 80 [3] => 11.25 )`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do:

```
$group_wages_array[6];
```

And

```
$thegroup['group_id'] = 6;
```

You can substitute this in as the key.

```
if (array_key_exists($thegroup['group_id'], $group_wages_array)) {
    $this_wages = $group_wages_array[$thegroup['group_id']];   
}
```

Comment: OK great, it worked when I used double brackets `$this_wages = $combined_group_wages[$thegroup['group_id']];`

Comment: You are correct, that was a syntax error, it should be correct now.  Thanks for pointing that out.